# Instagram API returning inconsistent results for liked photos and hashtagged photos

Tags: php, api, oauth, instagram

My app is live and I noticed the recent media for liked photos and hashtagged photos is inconsistent. I am using my app, Instagram on my phone, and Iconosquare.com to compare.

## 1 - My app doesn't seem to be able to see private photos. Sometimes it will receive them in the list of photos, but the image url itself with show broken. Other times the image just doesn't show up in the list. Iconosquare can access them all.

## 2 - For the hashtag I noticed that the most recent 10 are totally different. On my phone it is missing a few recently tagged photos, on my app its showing those missing ones but has an older photo as #2, and Iconosquare the first 3 loaded are older.

So my question is, are these "normal bugs" or am I doing something wrong. I am not using signed requests, is that the difference maker?

Comment: I started getting some weird behavior from the Instagram API the last 24 hours. Paging is inconsistent and seems very buggy (using min_tag_id and max_tag_id) and returns very old posts mixed with newer. Don't know what's wrong or if they are working on a fix, since there is rally no way of getting in touch with Instagrams devs

Comment: Thanks! I'm also wondering if it's partially the new algorithm at play. I know they say it won't be released officially, but I do notice some days the feed seems to be all people I like frequently and other days the feed is normal.

Comment: It seems weird that they would apply this change to the api as well. Paging through the result using min and max tag id, you'd expect to be able to get all results chronologically. Especially if you are using the data to perform analysis (which is one of their approved api use cases)